# Build ng-pattern of angularjs from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have many text boxes using `ng-pattern="/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{1,2})?$/"`. I want to centralize the this pattern. I created a variable in js file. It looks like `vm.ngPatternAmount = "/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{1,2})?$/";`. After that, I changed all ng-pattern on my form to `ng-pattern={{vm.ngPatternAmount}}`. But It did not work. Please help me to check it.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes needed are:
In Html:

```
ng-pattern='vm.ngPatternAmount'
```

in JS:

```
vm.ngPatternAmount = /^\d{0,10}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;//(don't put expression in quotes)
```